# Is it possible to correlate goals with search terms in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a goal set up (let's say the goal is "buy a product"), and I can see which search terms lead to the most conversions. However, I want to know which search terms lead to which products. Is it possible to track this? There are more products than the maximum number of goals you can create, so I can't just make lots of goals.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of of the [Advanced Segments](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108040) to view this information.

Create your own segment with a product name, SKU, or category dimension (you can create a segment for each product or just edit the one you're using to see different products) **and** a Metrics->Total Goal Conversions value >= 1

You can then enable your advanced segment and go to the Traffic Sources -> Keywords report to see which keywords convert for the product/SKU/category set in your segment.

Comment: There are a LOT of products, and we don't want to view search terms by product for a given product... We want to see all search terms versus all products if that makes any sense. What I've done in the meantime is a custom report of # of conversions versus keywords, which is very informative, but not quite what I was looking for. Is this something that would be better done server-side? (It's a lot easier to pull what was booked server-side, the tricky part is the keywords!)

Comment: @ZoFreX - You could store the contents of the `utmctr` cookie at checkout - this cookie should contain the keyword phrase which the visitor arrived with.